# Need help to install mac os x

Tags: mac

I have hp mini 210-2080nr booted windows 8 i have retail os x 10.6.3 copy please help to install it.I want to install it using only windows.

Comment: You want to build a hackintosh?

Comment: Hi Armen, Welcome to the site - Can I ask that you spend some more time making your question easier to understand?  I appreciate it doesn't look like English is your first language, but if you can add more information about what you are trying to achieve then more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows machine I assume you expect to virtualize OSX. With that assumption the answer is this:

You cannot legally virtualize Snow Leopard 10.6+ you can virtualize Lion 10.7+ though.

[This forum post vaguely details the issues with Apple and OSX Snow Leopard and virtualization.](http://www.itworld.com/answers/topic/virtualization/question/can-i-virtualize-snow-leopard-lion)

Furthermore, if you dont care about legality, [this may or may not invalidate your license of SnowLeopard but works](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080805081909302) in [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)